# Analytical Inverse function of exponential function of polynomials

Tags: inverse-function

How can I obtain the inverse of the function below analytically?

$$e^{(0.0116t^2-0.4212t)},\ \ \ 0<t \leq 7.0633$$

Someone insists that it can be analytically obtained.

Comment: Welcome to math.SE: in order to get the best possible answers, it is helpful if you say in what context you encountered the problem, and what your thoughts on it are; this will prevent people from telling you things you already know, and help them give their answers at the right level.

Answer (score 1):

Let:
$$y=e^{0.0116t^2-0.4212t}$$
Then, taking logarithms on both sides:
$$\ln{y}=0.0116t^2-0.4212t$$
Therefore:
$$0.0116t^2-0.4212t-\ln{y}=0$$
Note that you can now use the quadratic formula to solve explicitly for $t$.

Comment: I don't why I never thought to use quadratic formula there. Thank you :)